# Reuse ToggleButton-Style in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, togglebutton

I have the following ToggleButton-Style:

```
<Style x:Key="GraphToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Image Source="{StaticResource Graph}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Image Source="{StaticResource Graph_Off}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I'm trying to reuse this for my ToggleButtons (it's a list) - so every item in my list has one ToggleButton. The problem is, that when I click on my ToggleButton, the icon of the buttons, which aren't clicked disappears. Only my clicked button shows the desired image... Am I doing something wrong with this style?

My ToggleButton-Implementation:

```
 <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource GraphToggleButtonStyle}"
               ToolTip="{x:Static res:Resources.UseGraphToggle}"
               Visibility="{Binding Selected,
               Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

Comment: It's probably because you control the Visibility property on the button. Why are you doing that?

Comment: It's the same Visibility Property. I need to hide the buttons in some circumstances - but this works fine most of the time.

Comment: Are you definitely sure on the correct reference of the Graph_Off image? Try to swap the keys in the style, so that the unchecked image will be displayed as the checked one...just for test

Comment: the click-event gets fired :( i swaped the images with no result

Comment: no result? what's up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add child (Image) into Visual Tree whenever button `IsChecked` property changes.

Issue is **Style's are shared by default** unless you set **`x:Shared="False"`** and second any **Visual can be added only in one Visual tree**. If you add Visual in another Visual tree, it will be removed form previous Visual tree. Visual in your case is Image control.

In your case setting **`x:Shared="False"`** will work but that will break the re-usability feature of resources. So, I would suggest instead of creating new instance of `Image` control everytime, **create Image control only once and in triggers change the Image Source**.

```
<Style x:Key="GraphToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image x:Name="image"/>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked,
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                AncestorType=ToggleButton}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source"
                                Value="{StaticResource Graph}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked,
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                AncestorType=ToggleButton}}" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source"
                                Value="{StaticResource Graph_Off}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Image` in your style is a visual. One visual can only be used once in the visual tree. Instead of reusing the style let WPF create a new one each time its referenced:

```
<Style x:Key="GraphToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Shared="False">
....
```